# How to run react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu?

Tags: reactjs, npm, sidebar

I tried to install the npm but I keep getting errors on the sample code on the npm page of react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu. I also checked the GitHub repo and the demo website and I went through the explanation code and I did not get anywhere!

```
import SidebarMenu from 'react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu';

<SidebarMenu>
  <SidebarMenu.Header>
    <SidebarMenu.Brand>
      {/* Your brand icon */}
    </SidebarMenu.Brand>
    <SidebarMenu.Toggle />
  </SidebarMenu.Header>
  <SidebarMenu.Body>
    <SidebarMenu.Nav>
      <SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
          {/* Menu item icon */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          {/* Menu item title */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
      </SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
    <SidebarMenu.Nav/>
    <SidebarMenu.Sub>
      <SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon />
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          {/* Submenu title */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
      </SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle>
      <SidebarMenu.Sub.Collapse>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav>
          <SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
            <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
              {/* Submenu item icon */}
            </SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
            <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
              {/* Submenu item title */}
            </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          </SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
        </SidebarMenu.Nav>
      </SidebarMenu.Sub.Collapse>
    </SidebarMenu.Sub>
  <SidebarMenu.Body/>
</SidebarMenu>
```

as you can see some of the close tags are like this  </SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle>. I changed all tags to something like this one <SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle/> and I do not get any more errors but also I cannot see any sidebar menu!

Do you guys have any idea what should I do to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to import `.scss` styling coming with the package. Sadly I do not use scss, thus I'll drop the package.

`@import 'react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu/dist/sidebar-menu.scss';`

Answer (score 0):

The example in the documentation had some issues previously, but it has since been resolved. You can now directly copy the code snippet from the library's repository. Alternatively, you can review the following example for further clarification: - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu-ck23cz?file=/src/App.jsx